# hazelcast instance is running but unable to connect to mancenter

Tags: hazelcast

I have created created two gradle project.
First a libary project (**hazellib**), wrap hazelcast functionality and provide api to configure and can be used by any project to run hazelcast service.

The Second project (**projectA**) which consume this library. The projectA has following gradle script to add "hazellib" as dependency.

```
**buildscript {
      dependencies {
          classpath "com.components:hazellib:0.0.1"
          }
      }
  dependencies {
      compile   "com.components:hazellib:0.0.1"
  }**
```

With this setting **ProjectA** run fine but while opening **http://localhost:8080/mancenter/** it can not find the instance running locally.

The issue is to solve this problem I have to include 
compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.8.2"
in dependencies again beside the fact that it has already been referenced and included as dependencies in hazellib project. 
If I include this compile in dependencies (*not under buildscript) everything works fine and hazelcast serivce running locally can connect to mancenter or mancenter can detect instance running locally.

Can anyone suggest help me to understand what is missing here ? Isn't including depedencies ,compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.8.2" in hazellib project gradle script is enough for project that are using the lib to run halzelcast locally ? Why should I add same dependecies again in project **ProjectA** again ?

Here hazelcast log . It clrealy shows that the instance has started and infact it can be access and cache is working fine but mancenter is not able to detect it. As soon as I add compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.8.2" in gradle mancenter will be able to connect to the instance as well.

Members [1] {Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 - aa25f0ac-da88-432b-87fc-f7247b437c1a this
} INFO  c.h.i.m.ManagementCenterService - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [hazelcast_cache] [3.7.7] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast Management Center on address: http://localhost:8080/mancenter
INFO  c.h.internal.jmx.ManagementService - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [hazelcast_cache] [3.7.7] Hazelcast JMX agent enabled[hz.hazelcastDefaultInstance.MC.State.Sender] INFO  c.h.i.p.impl.PartitionStateManager - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [hazelcast_cache] [3.7.7] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
INFO  com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService - [127.0.0.1]:5701 [hazelcast_cache] [3.7.7] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTED

Comment: Can you post the logs that show what Hazelcast is doing ?

Comment: Hello Neil, I have updated question with log . It shows that hazelcast instance is up and running but mancenter is not able to detect and connect to it. But as soon as I add  **compile "com.hazelcast:hazelcast:3.8.2"** as dependencies in gradle script and restart the application it works fine and mancenter will be able to detect and connect to the instance.

Comment: Could be a versions thing. What version of Mancenter are you using ? In your logs Hazelcast lists as version 3.7.7 but if you change the dependency you get version 3.8.2. If possible, you should upgrade Mancenter to 3.9 and Hazelcast to 3.9, may as well go for the latest if this is something you can vary.

Comment: I updated dependencies to 3.9 (hazelcast) in my library and I have mancenter 3.9 already but still I am seeing the same issue. Looking at log it still initialize 3.7.7 and once I compile my project I am seeing 3.7.7 jar begin downloaded and populated in gradle cache . Wondering why it keep downloading 3.7.7 even though I have 3.9 as dependency. I tried to exclude 3.7.7 version from compile and classpath but it still download the 3.7.7 jar. I need more investigation but if you have any idea please share. If I resolve the issue will update accordingly.

Comment: Btw , I just verified its definitely version mismatch issue between hazelcast and mancenter . When I downgraded mancenter version to use 3.7.7 it worked fine and is able to connect/detect hazelcast  instance (in  my case as i mentioned the lib has 3.9 as dependency but some how 3.7.7 is being downloaded) . Based on out come I will up vote your answer and continue to fix on my side and resolve issue of dependency mismatch.

Comment: You using Spring Boot as well ? It's `spring-boot-dependencies` module sets a property `hazelcast.version`. You can override it.

Comment: Yes it  is spring boot . Adding ext["hazelcast.version"] = "3.9" in build.gradle resolve the issue as you suggested. This addition is done in main project, If I add same in library project that would not help. The elegant way would be to add or force correct version in library project but at this time or till I don't wrap my head around dependency management in gradle I will use this solution.

Comment: @NRA I believe yo'd have given url like- http://localhost:8080/mancenter and 3.7.7 in pom.xml. mancenter also with 3.7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer based on the comments trail, set `hazelcast.version` if using Spring Boot to select a Hazelcast IMDG server version compatible with the Management Center version.